# Clickable Material Design Icons

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, material-design

I have finished placing three material design icons in my toolbar and was wondering how to be able to click them and have intents.
Here is the activity class code:

```
package com.example.patri.index01;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Lines extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lines);

        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The layout.xml:

```
<android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".Lines">
       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#000000">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LINES"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

The menu.xml/main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  tools:context=".Lines">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_add"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_wheel"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  int i = item.getItemId();
  switch (i) {
    case R.id.action_search:
      //do your stuff here
      return true;

    case R.id.action_add:
      //do your stuff here
      return true;

    case R.id.action_wheel:
      //do your stuff here
      return true;            
   }

   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Override this function and perform your actions based on `i`.

Comment: I was going to change it :)

Comment: I will add an edit to show you what I'm talking about, but the second to last brace is giving me an error.

Comment: I just added return true; after return super.onOptionItemSelected(item); Thank you so much!

Comment: I see your new edits now. Thanks. Sorry but I'm getting another error on break; it says its unreachable.

Comment: Sorry, I usually use an if statement. You can remove the break because return true will act as a pseudo break.

Answer (score 0):

Write click event handling code in `onMenuItemClick()` event.